# Parsing and extract JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Need some guidance for the JSON below, i am trying to extract the characterID, how should i go about it?

Thanks in advance,

The JSON output i was envisioning is,

```
 "data2": {
         "characterId1": "2305843009261174417",
         "characterId2": "2305843009261174418",
         "characterId3": "2305843009283296434"

         }
```

The JSON is as below:

```
{
  "characters": {
    "data": {
      "2305843009261174417": {
        "membershipId": "4611686018445971568",
        "membershipType": 2,
        "characterId": "2305843009261174417"

        }

      },
      "2305843009261174418": {
        "membershipId": "4611686018445971568",
        "membershipType": 2,
        "characterId": "2305843009261174418"

        }

      },
      "2305843009283296434": {
        "membershipId": "4611686018445971568",
        "membershipType": 2,
        "characterId": "2305843009283296434"

        }


      }

}
```

Comment: please edit your question and write the JSON data you have and your expected output

Comment: ' No implicit conversion from String to integer'. You are getting this error because the key variable is string and you are giving this string as parameter that defined in integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to normalize your parameters first, because currently it is

```
{
  "characters": {
    "data": {
      "2305843009261174417": {
        "membershipId": "4611686018445971568",
        "membershipType": 2,
        "characterId": "2305843009261174417"
      }
    },
    "2305843009261174418": {
      "membershipId": "4611686018445971568",
      "membershipType": 2,
      "characterId": "2305843009261174418"
    }
  },
  "2305843009283296434": {
    "membershipId": "4611686018445971568",
    "membershipType": 2,
    "characterId": "2305843009283296434"
  }
}
}
```

and your expected output is wrong, you can't have same keys in Hash

```
"data2": {
  "characterId": "2305843009261174417",
  "characterId": "2305843009261174418",
  "characterId": "2305843009283296434"
}
```

look, data2 key has three characterId keys

Comment: yes, you are right, edited. should be characterId1, 2 and 3.

Comment: check my updated answer above, I re-forrmatted your JSON input to be more readable, it's not valid JSON, there is closing bracket in the end of the line